# font awesome icon is just a square

Tags: html, css

I place the link in the index head tag and my main css file is being imported

```
       <a href="github.com">
        <i class="fab fa-github-square"></i>
      </a>
      <a href="www.sourcetree.com">
        <i class="fab fa-github-square"></i>
      </a>
      <a href="www.bitbu.com">
        <i class="fab fa-github-square"></i>
      </a>
```

Comment: this is the font link im using  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: You are using font awesome version 4, so you need to use the class "fa' instead of "fab"

Comment: If you refer to anything with the absolute url, you must include the protocol: ```http://...``` eg. I noticed your href's are also missing this.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've also uploaded the /fonts/ directory when using self-hosted Font Awesome. https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/hosting-font-awesome-yourself

Answer (score 0):

after you sure css file is reading correctly , look at the example:

https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/icon/address-book

class should be like this:

```
<i class="fa fa-address-book" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

pay attention to "fa" class